# How to display multiple row data as comma separated

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to fetch data from two different database on basis of where condition
In which i am fetching user name, address, pin code ,street address and languages they are spoken. Now problem is i have multiple row data for languages for same user like following.

```
pid field_languages_spoken_value
 1    English
 1    Spanish
 2    English
```

Now how I can display them as "English, Spanish".

My code for the query:

```
SELECT x.field_name_value, 
       x.field_street_address_value, 
       x.field_zip_code_value, 
       x.field_street_address_value, 
       x.field_zip_code_value, 
       x.field_test_tid, 
       x.field_test_tid, 
       x.field_county_value, 
       x.field_county_value, 
       x.field_name_value, 
       x.field_address_value, 
       x.field_county_value, 
       x.mail, 
       x.field_name_value, 
       x.field_languages_spoken_value, 
       x.field_languages_spoken_value, 
       x.field_address_value, 
       x.field_county_value, 
       x.mail 
FROM   (SELECT a.field_name_value, 
               b.field_address_value, 
               c.field_county_value, 
               d.field_test_tid, 
               e.mail, 
               k.field_street_address_value, 
               l.field_zip_code_value, 
               p.uid, 
               Group_concat(Distinct lang.field_languages_spoken_value) 
        FROM   db1.users e 
               INNER JOIN db1.profile AS p 
                       ON p.uid = e.uid 
               INNER JOIN db1.field_data_field_languages_spoken AS lang 
                       ON lang.entity_id = p.pid 
               INNER JOIN db1.field_data_field_name AS a 
                       ON a.entity_id = p.pid 
               INNER JOIN db1.field_data_field_address AS b 
                       ON b.entity_id = p.pid 
               INNER JOIN db1.field_data_field_county AS c 
                       ON c.entity_id = p.pid 
               INNER JOIN db1.field_data_field_street_address AS k 
                       ON k.entity_id = p.pid 
               INNER JOIN db1.field_data_field_zip_code AS l 
                       ON l.entity_id = p.pid 
               INNER JOIN db1.field_data_field_test AS d 
                       ON d.entity_id = p.pid 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT f.field_name_value, 
               g.field_address_value, 
               h.field_county_value, 
               i.field_test_tid, 
               j.mail, 
               m.field_street_address_value, 
               n.field_zip_code_value, 
               q.uid, 
               Group_concat(Distinct lange.field_languages_spoken_value) 
        FROM   db2.users j 
               INNER JOIN db2.profile AS q 
                       ON q.uid = j.uid 
               INNER JOIN db2.field_data_field_languages_spoken AS lange 
                       ON lange.entity_id = q.pid 
               INNER JOIN db2.field_data_field_name AS f 
                       ON f.entity_id = q.pid 
               INNER JOIN db2.field_data_field_address AS g 
                       ON g.entity_id = q.pid 
               INNER JOIN db2.field_data_field_county AS h 
                       ON h.entity_id = q.pid 
               INNER JOIN db2.field_data_field_street_address AS m 
                       ON m.entity_id = q.pid 
               INNER JOIN db2.field_data_field_zip_code AS n 
                       ON n.entity_id = q.pid 
               INNER JOIN db2.field_data_field_test AS i 
                       ON i.entity_id = q.pid) AS x 
WHERE  x.field_county_value LIKE :city 
       AND x.field_test_tid LIKE :speciality
```

How do I go about this problem.

Comment: give alias name to group_concat field as field_languages_spoken_value.

Comment: Like this group_concat(x.field_languages_spoken_value)

Comment: Nops like this Group_concat(lang.field_languages_spoken_value) as field_languages_spoken_value.

Comment: Yup it works but i have only two rows. 1 is english and 2nd is spanish but it display "english,english,english,english,spanish,spanish,spanish)

Comment: use distinct. group_concat(distinct lang.field_languages_spoken_value) as field_languages_spoken_value.

Comment: Sir, please check this #1370 - execute command denied to user 'law'@'localhost' for routine 'distinct.Group_concat'

Comment: dont use distinct.group_concat. Use group_concat(distinct lang.field_languages_spoken_value) as field_languages_spoken_value.

Comment: For what you are trying to achieve, that query is going to be a dog when it comes to performance! If you have the breathing room, I'd honestly think about taking a step back and reevaluating what you are really trying to achieve. It looks quite a lot like you are trying to do everything within a single query just because you can.

Comment: Please reconsider thinking about your SQL query. The inner subquery will return ALL the rows. And the outer one will not benefit of the indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Separator inside group concat

```
GROUP_CONCAT(lange.field_languages_spoken_value SEPARATOR ',')
```

And group it by uid

Hope the result is same as your expected :)

[EDITED]:
Try this query I have modify it hope there is no error in there and make the result as your expected :)

```
SELECT x.field_name_value, 
   x.field_street_address_value, 
   x.field_zip_code_value, 
   x.field_street_address_value, 
   x.field_zip_code_value, 
   x.field_test_tid, 
   x.field_test_tid, 
   x.field_county_value, 
   x.field_county_value, 
   x.field_name_value, 
   x.field_address_value, 
   x.field_county_value, 
   x.mail, 
   x.field_name_value, 
   x.field_languages_spoken_value, 
   x.field_languages_spoken_value, 
   x.field_address_value, 
   x.field_county_value, 
   x.mail 
FROM   (SELECT a.field_name_value, 
           b.field_address_value, 
           c.field_county_value, 
           d.field_test_tid, 
           e.mail, 
           k.field_street_address_value, 
           l.field_zip_code_value, 
           p.uid, 
           lange.field_languages_spoken_value 
    FROM   db1.users e 
           INNER JOIN db1.profile AS p 
                   ON p.uid = e.uid 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT lange1.entity_id,GROUP_CONCAT(lange1.field_languages_spoken_value SEPARATOR ',') as `field_languages_spoken_value` FROM db1.field_data_field_languages_spoken lange1 GROUP BY lange1.entity_id) AS lange
                   ON lang.entity_id = p.pid 
           INNER JOIN db1.field_data_field_name AS a 
                   ON a.entity_id = p.pid 
           INNER JOIN db1.field_data_field_address AS b 
                   ON b.entity_id = p.pid 
           INNER JOIN db1.field_data_field_county AS c 
                   ON c.entity_id = p.pid 
           INNER JOIN db1.field_data_field_street_address AS k 
                   ON k.entity_id = p.pid 
           INNER JOIN db1.field_data_field_zip_code AS l 
                   ON l.entity_id = p.pid 
           INNER JOIN db1.field_data_field_test AS d 
                   ON d.entity_id = p.pid 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT f.field_name_value, 
           g.field_address_value, 
           h.field_county_value, 
           i.field_test_tid, 
           j.mail, 
           m.field_street_address_value, 
           n.field_zip_code_value, 
           q.uid, 
           lange.field_languages_spoken_value
    FROM   db2.users j 
           INNER JOIN db2.profile AS q 
                   ON q.uid = j.uid
       INNER JOIN (SELECT lange2.entity_id,GROUP_CONCAT(lange2.field_languages_spoken_value SEPARATOR ',') as `field_languages_spoken_value` FROM db2.field_data_field_languages_spoken lange2 GROUP BY lange2.entity_id) AS lange 
                   ON lange.entity_id = q.pid 
           INNER JOIN db2.field_data_field_name AS f 
                   ON f.entity_id = q.pid 
           INNER JOIN db2.field_data_field_address AS g 
                   ON g.entity_id = q.pid 
           INNER JOIN db2.field_data_field_county AS h 
                   ON h.entity_id = q.pid 
           INNER JOIN db2.field_data_field_street_address AS m 
                   ON m.entity_id = q.pid 
           INNER JOIN db2.field_data_field_zip_code AS n 
                   ON n.entity_id = q.pid 
           INNER JOIN db2.field_data_field_test AS i 
                   ON i.entity_id = q.pid) AS x 
WHERE  x.field_county_value LIKE :city 
AND x.field_test_tid LIKE :speciality
```

Comment: No, I have only 2 row .they display like English,English,English,English,spanish,spanish,spanish,

Comment: i used tri hartanto code ,Its executing but displaying duplicate result.please help I also use distinct keyword but of no use. when i executed this code in mysql its display correctly but while executing  in program page its shows duplicate values

Comment: I used group by for p.pid and q.pid , It executed successfully.Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
SELECT x.field_name_value, 
           x.field_street_address_value, 
           x.field_zip_code_value, 
           x.field_street_address_value, 
           x.field_zip_code_value, 
           x.field_test_tid, 
           x.field_test_tid, 
           x.field_county_value, 
           x.field_county_value, 
           x.field_name_value, 
           x.field_address_value, 
           x.field_county_value, 
           x.mail, 
           x.field_name_value, 
           x.field_languages_spoken_value, 
           x.field_languages_spoken_value, 
           x.field_address_value, 
           x.field_county_value, 
           x.mail 
    FROM   (SELECT a.field_name_value, 
                   b.field_address_value, 
                   c.field_county_value, 
                   d.field_test_tid, 
                   e.mail, 
                   k.field_street_address_value, 
                   l.field_zip_code_value, 
                   p.uid, 
                   Group_concat(distinct lang.field_languages_spoken_value) as field_languages_spoken_value
            FROM   db1.users e 
                   INNER JOIN db1.profile AS p 
                           ON p.uid = e.uid 
                   INNER JOIN db1.field_data_field_languages_spoken AS lang 
                           ON lang.entity_id = p.pid 
                   INNER JOIN db1.field_data_field_name AS a 
                           ON a.entity_id = p.pid 
                   INNER JOIN db1.field_data_field_address AS b 
                           ON b.entity_id = p.pid 
                   INNER JOIN db1.field_data_field_county AS c 
                           ON c.entity_id = p.pid 
                   INNER JOIN db1.field_data_field_street_address AS k 
                           ON k.entity_id = p.pid 
                   INNER JOIN db1.field_data_field_zip_code AS l 
                           ON l.entity_id = p.pid 
                   INNER JOIN db1.field_data_field_test AS d 
                           ON d.entity_id = p.pid 
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT f.field_name_value, 
                   g.field_address_value, 
                   h.field_county_value, 
                   i.field_test_tid, 
                   j.mail, 
                   m.field_street_address_value, 
                   n.field_zip_code_value, 
                   q.uid, 
                   Group_concat(distinct lange.field_languages_spoken_value) as field_languages_spoken_value
            FROM   db2.users j 
                   INNER JOIN db2.profile AS q 
                           ON q.uid = j.uid 
                   INNER JOIN db2.field_data_field_languages_spoken AS lange 
                           ON lange.entity_id = q.pid 
                   INNER JOIN db2.field_data_field_name AS f 
                           ON f.entity_id = q.pid 
                   INNER JOIN db2.field_data_field_address AS g 
                           ON g.entity_id = q.pid 
                   INNER JOIN db2.field_data_field_county AS h 
                           ON h.entity_id = q.pid 
                   INNER JOIN db2.field_data_field_street_address AS m 
                           ON m.entity_id = q.pid 
                   INNER JOIN db2.field_data_field_zip_code AS n 
                           ON n.entity_id = q.pid 
                   INNER JOIN db2.field_data_field_test AS i 
                           ON i.entity_id = q.pid) AS x 
    WHERE  x.field_county_value LIKE :city 
           AND x.field_test_tid LIKE :speciality
```

Comment: its work but they will fetch all languages as distinct in table but not by userid.

Comment: all user languages are shown to every user like if user 1 has selected english and spanish and user 2 selected Scottish Gaelic then user 1 shows english,spanish, Scottish Gaelic

Comment: I have edited my answer and can you just please provide some data so that we can also check this query

Comment: Can you provide some data so that i can check where the mistake is

Comment: If i write group by lang.entity_id and for second group by lange.entity_id then it only display first database record

Comment: sorry can't imagine what would be the result now

Comment: try to do group by on uid